# How to show an icon after textfield as a "Help" to enter the values into the textfield

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4.1

I am using Extjs 4.1

I have a form with some textfields.

I want to show a help icon beside this textfield for allowing the user to enter the correct value, while the form is being displayed.

Can any body help me in solving this.

Comment: Please work on your rep before telling other users they shouldn't ask more questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using Ext.form.TriggerField in place of text field.

Refer Extjs docs for reference http://extjs.cachefly.net/ext-3.4.0/docs/

For ExtJs 4.1:

http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.form.field.Trigger

Comment: Thanks for ur reply.I have tried using triggers.Works fine.But the problem is,i want to show a tooltip when i place the mouse over that icon.How can i configure a tool tip for this icon? My code for the trigger is as follows
           xtype: 'trigger',
    fieldLabel: 'Srinivas',
    triggerCls: 'trigger',
      width:190

The Cls is

 .x-form-trigger-wrap .trigger{background-image:url('delete.png');background-position:0 0;width:17px;height:21px;border-bottom:0px solid #b5b8c8;cursor:pointer;cursor:hand;overflow:hidden;background-repeat: no-repeat}

Can u please help me in placing a tool tip.

Comment: Refer this link http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?66661-TriggerField-Icon-tooltip

Comment: @Jai Can i have an icon also beside the combo box ?

Comment: yes you can.. use tpl property of the combo.

countryCombo = Ext.create('Ext.form.field.ComboBox', {
    displayField : 'name',
    valueField   : 'code',
    grow         : true,
    store        : countryStore,
    queryMode    : 'local',
    listConfig: {
        getInnerTpl: function() {
            // here you place the images in your combo
            var tpl = '<div>'+
                      '<img src="images/flags/{iso2}.png" align="left">&nbsp;&nbsp;'+
                      '{name}</div>';
            return tpl;
        }
    }
});

Comment: TriggerField reports as deprecated in ExtJs 5: `[W] Ext.form.field.Trigger is deprecated. Use Ext.form.field.Text instead. `

Answer (score 11):

Simplest way imho is to place "help icon" at the end of label text using afterLabelTextTpl like this:

```
afterLabelTextTpl: '<img src="images/information.gif" class="info_image" data-qtip="your help text or even html comes here...."></img>'
```

Can be used with any field...

Answer (score 2):

I've made a plugin that makes use of the `afterLabelTextTpl` config of `Ext.form.Labelable` which is mixined to all kinds of fields like Combobox.

Here's how to use it.

```
{
    xtype: 'textfield',
    fieldLabel: 'Some field label',
    name: 'name',
    plugins:[{
        ptype:'afterlabelinfo',
        qtip:'The text appearing after hovering over the icon'
    }]
}
```

Here's the plugin you need.

```
Ext.define('Ext.ux.plugin.AfterLabelInfo', {
    extend: 'Ext.AbstractPlugin',
    alias: 'plugin.afterlabelinfo',

    init: function (cmp) {
        var me = this; // the plugin

        cmp.afterLabelTextTpl = [
            '<span',
            ' class="x-ux-plugin-afterlabelinfo"',
            ' data-qtip="',
            Ext.util.Format.htmlEncode(me.qtip || ''),
            '">',
            '</span>'
        ].join('');
    }
});
```

Here's some css that you need.

```
.x-ux-plugin-afterlabelinfo {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: 5px;
    width: 12px;
    height: 12px;
    background-image: url(img/info-after.png) !important;
}
```

And the icon [image] (right click and save as)

The result

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The best approach for me is to use Ext.tip.QuickTipView which can be easily added in afterrender event like this:

```
afterrender: function(me) {
  // Register the new tip with an element's ID
  Ext.tip.QuickTipManager.register({
     target: me.getId(), // Target button's ID
     text  : 'My Button has a QuickTip' // Tip content  
  });
}
```

https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.1/5.1.0-apidocs/#!/api/Ext.tip.QuickTip

Answer (score -2):

To add image to combo,

use tpl property of the combo.

```
 Combo = Ext.create('Ext.form.field.ComboBox', {
    displayField : 'name',
    valueField   : 'code',
    grow         : true,
    store        : store,
    queryMode    : 'local',
    listConfig: {
        getInnerTpl: function() {
            // here you place the images in your combo
            var tpl = '<div>'+
                      '<img src="images/flags/{iso2}.png" align="left">&nbsp;&nbsp;'+
                      '{name}</div>';
            return tpl;
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: This will render inside the combobox list, that's not the question here. He is asking for behind the field itself.